# Видно - наречие ( СКС) в функции сказуемого или краткое прилагательное

Tags: синтаксис

СКС обычно употребяются в безличном предложении, но пример в словаре на Грамоте.ру заставил меня засомневаться.

Пример:ВИДНО. **I. нареч., в функц. сказ.** Можно видеть, рассмотреть. С горы далеко в. Дом виден издалека. На горизонте видна туча.

В первом примере, ясно, нареч., в функц. сказ. А как насчет остальных двух примеров? Здесь краткое прилагательное или все же нареч. в функ. сказуемого?

> Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
>   Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***С горы далеко видно.***

Предложение безличное,  ***видно***  — СКС (слово категории состояния).

.

***Дом виден*** издалека. На горизонте ***видна туча.***

Предложения двусоставные, сказуемые ***виден, видна*** согласованы с подлежащими в роде, числе. ***Виден, видна***  — краткие прилагательные.

.

Из ***Бабайцевой ("Явления переходности в грамматике русского языка", М., 2000):***

> В двусоставных предложениях функционируют **бесспорные прилагательные,
>   если они имеют формы не среднего рода**. В таких случаях сочетающиеся
>   с ними существительные осознаются как подлежащие (а не дополнения!),
>   например:
>
> Отсюда вам ***будет видна*** наша ***встреча.***
>
> Скоро ***стали видны*** и ***развалины*** города.

Comment: Уже не в первый раз замечаю ошибки в словаре. Спасибо!

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x
Если Вы об этом, пользоваться этим словарём нельзя, он вообще странный. В нормальном словаре Кузнецова всё в порядке, примеры верные

Comment: http://enc-dic.com/kuzhecov/Vidno-49609.html
I. нареч., в функц. сказ. Можно видеть, рассмотреть. С горы далеко в. По глазам в., что врёт. Следов не в. Нигде никого не в. Не видно ни зги . Там  будет в. (будущее покажет. От земли не в. кого-л.  Видно птицу по полёту (посл.).
II. вводн. сл. Разг. По-видимому, вероятно. В., придётся уезжать.
◁ Как ви́дно, в зн. вводн. сл. По-видимому, вероятно. * По улицам слона водили, Как видно, напоказ (Крылов).
Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт С. А. Кузнецов. 1998

Comment: А в том присоединили и значение слова "видный", только как-то выборочно. Нужно писать на сайт об ошибках, а вообще лучше пользоваться бумажными словарями, в Интернете никто ни за что не отвечает, Ваше дело-доверять или нет.

Comment: Да, Людмила, я имела в виду именно этот словарь. Странно, что на таком портале столько ошибок.

Comment: Людмила, я тоже там видел много ошибок. Писал, ответа до сих не последовало.

Comment: Сейчас много "пиратских " сайтов, этот словарь  явно оттуда, как он попал на "Грамоту.ру", неизвестно. Значит, и там невнимательные люди. А может, скачали не оттуда и сразу не разобрались, не будут же весь словарь проверять, что-то верно, что-то нет. Я смотрю, сейчас много сайтов на проверке, на реконструкции, может, наведут порядок. А может,  Вы попали на пиратскую копию сайта,

Comment: Да нет. Именно тот сайт, на который вы дали ссылку. Вряд ли Грамота.ру будет откуда-то брать словари.